# Is there a way to check the status of "do not disturb" setting in iphone or android app?

Tags: android, ios, do-not-disturb

Currently I'm building ios and android apps on top of react native. I hope to check the status of "do not disturb" in phone settings so we can suggest user to turn it on if it's off. My question is: is there any way to check the status of "do not disturb" settings programmatically? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! I am completely missing a context here. Could you add a bit more, so people can answer your question better?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - Your answer is missing an awful lot of context, and it's next to impossible for people to know how to help without it. Please read - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: welcome @Quan, below are some pointers  to help you add details to your question:
1. specify the programming language your application is built on
2. any constraints ex: should this be asynchronous query from back end?
3. (optional) have you tried any approach and what was the result?